# Linux shared memory and L1/L2/L3 caches

Tags: linux, caching, memory, shared

I am trying to understand the relationship between shared memory in linux and the L[123] caches. From my brief research, I understand that the L* caches are completely independent from the shared memory, i.e. If I were to write something to shared memory, they do no get into the L* caches; so when a process reads from a shared memory segment, there are no caches in between whatsoever. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: As far as the cache hierarchy goes, shared memory is simply memory. When you have multiple CPUs with different caches, the hardware is responsible for keeping coherency between cache line copies in different hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks, so are you saying that reads from shared memory could potentially be served from the L* caches ?

Comment: Yes. What happens when two separate CPUs access the same cache line depends on your hardware. Some architectures allow a shared state, where  a cache line exists in multiple caches, as long as it's only ever read, some require a cache line to only ever exist in one cache, etc... But in any case, you shouldn't have to worry about it, because the hardware should be enforcing it's designated cache coherency protocols.

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true. On x86, load/store have acquire/release semantics, so one thread in a busy loop reading shared memory will see updates from another thread writing shared memory. On some other architectures, this doesn't work without memory fence instructions too. If you're writing in C, the compiler itself can also cause reordering/duplication/coalescing of memory accesses. This should only be an issue if you're trying to write lockless code; for most (lock-ful?) code, there's already memory barriers in all the lock functions.

Comment: I am actually trying to write lockless code where I have one writer and multiple readers and I am managing this using two counters around the memory being written. Say the counters are C1, C2. Writer increments C1, updates the memory area and then increments C2. Reader reads C2, reads the memory area, and then reads C1; if C1 != C2, it discards what it read. What I am worried here is, when the reader reads C1, is it possible for it to get the old value of C1 from the cache ? If it does, then this model won't work.

Comment: Reading and writing multiple memory locations? Even on x86 (which has the strictest memory ordering out of all common architectures) you need explicit memory fences to guarantee ordering. **edit** I'm also not sure if I understand correctly, because that model seems broken, even with total ordering. Writer writes C1 and half of memory. Reader reads C1 and all of memory. Writer writes the rest of memory then C2. Reader reads C2, which is now equal to C1, but reader has read half-written and inconsistent memory.

Comment: @ephemient, the writer and reader write/read C1/C2 in the opposite order.

Comment: @Omprakaash It doesn't matter, because it's not guaranteed that loads/stores to different addresses will be visible to other CPUs in the same order. There are memory fence or cache flush instructions that will ensure you see the right ordering at the CPU level. In languages like C and Java you will also need some extra methods because this requires stricter ordering than the languages' default memory model too.

Comment: @ephemient - ok, agreed, Can you point me to the cache flush instructions for linux ?

Comment: It still depends on what architecture you're on and which programming language you're using.

Comment: say x86_[32/64] and C.

Comment: With C11 atomics?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use the C11 programming language yet. If I simply use the volatile keyword while reading/writing to the counters, can I not get away with it ?

Comment: No, that doesn't give you sequentially-consistent ordering (in C).

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, I guess I need to use the memory fences both in my reader and writer when reading the counters. I plan on using Acquire_Load to read the counters and Acquire_Store() when writing to them. Would that close the race completely ?

Comment: I'm not sure where your Acquire_Load and Acquire_Store come from, but in C11 parlance, `memory_order_acquire`, `memory_order_release`, and `memory_order_acq_rel` are insufficient; you need `memory_order_seq_cst`. They unfortunately only guarantee the ordering of *atomic* operations, so if you're using non-atomic operations on your memory area: well, I think it'll work on x86, but it might depend on the compiler. Are you sure you wouldn't rather use locks?